# How to handle drift with Azure Data Factory Trigger and Terraform

Tags: terraform, azure-data-factory, terraform-provider-azure

I have a number of triggers defined in the terraform code and all is good when I first deploy everything.

```
resource "azurerm_data_factory_trigger_schedule" "some_trigger" {
    activated           = var.trigger_enabled
```

The problem is that if any attributes of trigger change then the update fails because you need to disable the trigger prior to updating it.

I therefore added

```
resource "null_resource" "stop_trigger" {
triggers = {
    activated    = var.trigger_enabled
```

with an AZ CLI script to stop the trigger and made the actual trigger resource dependant on it.

That works until someone enables a disabled trigger via the portal.

When this happens `terraform init` correctly identifies the drift on the trigger resource and tries to update it but the `null_resource` doesn't get triggered so it fails because the trigger is enabled.

I tried setting the `null_resource` to trigger all the time but this then stops the triggers that haven't changed but obviously the actual trigger resource doesn't get run so the trigger it never re-enabled.

Is there a way I can get this to work where by the triggers that are in need of update (including those that have have suffered drift) get set to what is defined in the terraform code?

Comment: Maybe this could work: https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle? Try with `ignore_changes`?

Comment: It sounds like your `null_resource` triggers are not set accurately. Without seeing your config it is unclear what the triggers should be. They are normally based off of exported attributes from resources that chain into them. Consider also extricating `null_resource` from your config as it is a bit of a "last resort" anyway.

Comment: @MattSchuchard the `null_resource` is a last resort as the azure provider does not seem to handle updating an enabled trigger (but it does try and then fails).  The trigger here is a variable which gets passed into the module.  Essentially if the status or schedule change I want to have terraform update the trigger but it needs to stop them before it can do so.   The triggers are therefore the variables used to control the status and schedule as not sure what else I could use? but these obviously don't reflect the current state of the trigger